# checking two conditions using while loop in bash script

Tags: bash, while-loop, conditional-statements, multiple-conditions

I want to check if the user has not entered 'y' or 'n' and if not then to keep looping asking the user to entered the correct letter but it is not working... the code below shows what I have tried so far ....can someone help me please???

```
echo "Enter 'y' to exit or 'n' to continue" 
echo -n "Do you want to exit? "
read character

while [ "$character" != "y" || "$character" != "n" ];
do

    echo -n "Wrong key re-enter 'y' to exit or 'n' to continue"
    read character
done
```

Comment: `$var != y || $var != n` is **always** true. Anything that isn't `y` will make the first part true and `y` will make the second part true.

Comment: so, how do I make it false then

Comment: Think about the logic of what you are trying to test. Do you want `$var` is not `x` **OR** not `y`? Or do you want `$var` is not `x` **AND** not `y`?

Comment: can you talking to me about the difference because now I am a bit confused about what I want it to do.....sorry

Comment: A variable value can *either* equal `y` *OR* it can equal `n`. You need to check whether *either* of these conditions holds. So you *either* want to check `$var = y || $var = n` (it **is** one or the other of the values you care about *or* you wan to check `$var != y && $var != n` (it **is not** either of the values you care about... it is not `y` and it is not `n`).

Comment: yes, I see...What I want is that if it is not either of the values (it is not Y and it is not N either) - that is what I am looking for...please

Comment: Which I just gave you the pseudo-code for. Add the requisite bash test  syntax and you have it.

Comment: Thank you very much it still showing stupid errors that I cannot understand it - can I send you the whole function so you can check for me where I got a errors....pleaaaaaase

Comment: If you've fixed that problem and have more problems then ask a new question with your updated script and the new problems.

Comment: Also use [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) on your code.

Comment: @CrislyDomingos He just gave you the answer. But I recommend that you take a look at this link: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot to all of you... after a good persistence and resilience I finally found the answer of what I was looking for... A posted the code below:

```
#if the user's input is not Y or N
while [[ $(read -sn1; echo ${character^^})  =~ [^YN] ]];
do
    echo -n "Re-enter 'y' to exit or 'n'to continue: ?"
    read character
done
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just:

```
while [[ $(read -sn1 character; echo ${character^^})  =~ [^YN] ]]; do
  echo -n "Wrong key ..."
done
```

- you'll want -s unless you want the key echoed
- you will want to have -n1 to limit the input to ONE character
- you can also check for ctrl+c and ctrl+d pressed via $? (ctrl-d is 1 and ctrl+c is 130, but ctrl+d catching only works if you include the -e flag and use readline)
- you can include a prompt in there too if you want, and also, you dont have to use '$character' you can just give it nothing and check $REPLY
- if you really dont want ctrl+c pressed at all consider using a trap

Answer (score 0):

This approach tries to account for more user possibilities and still accomplish the same thing.

```
#if the user's input is not Y or N, Yes or No, y or n, yes or no
while [[ ! "$character" =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]] && [[ ! "$character" =~ ^([nN][oO]|[nN])$ ]]
do
    echo -n "Wrong key re-enter 'y' to exit or 'n' to continue"
    read character
done
```